# Having trouble to decode json string

Tags: json

I have an json string i want to parse to small array of objects, i am using decoder for that but it wont help, why is this happining?

I have defined the variable as $cleanforcharacters

```
$cleanforcharacters = preg_replace('/["{mtwrdayfsasusseto}"]_/', '', $found['newdiscounthours']);
```

this is my output

```
discount_org: "{"day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10","day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10"}"
```

this is desired output (array of objects)

```
discount_org: [
{
day: 0,
time: 8,
discount: 10
},
{
day: 0,
time: 14,
discount: 10
},
```

this is how i tried

$arrayOfEmails = json_decode($cleanforcharacters);

and this is what i am getting now

```
discount_org: {
day: "20",
time: "12:00",
discount: "20"
}
```

the rest is not coming out either

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared that as an object and the keys are overriding the values rather than being set as new values:-

You have given:-

```
discount_org: "{"day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10","day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10"}"
```

It should be:-

```
discount_org: "[{"day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10"},{"day":"8:00","time":"12:00","discount":"10"}]"
```

Then use:-

```
$arrayOfEmails = json_decode($cleanforcharacters,true);
```

This would give you correct result.

Comment: Well is it not because it is a string and not a object? If so, i dont think the decoder works with strings